# how do you rest your steak after cooking

Tags: beef, steak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to rest meat but not let it get too cold?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/how-to-rest-meat-but-not-let-it-get-too-cold)

I have been over the last year perfecting the home cooked steak to my liking and have read with interest the questions and answers on cooking steak [How do you properly cook a steak?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/267/how-do-you-properly-cook-a-steak)  and [How do you cook a steak like those found in fine steakhouses?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/how-do-you-cook-a-steak-like-those-found-in-fine-steakhouses)

But I find that when I rest it properly it gets too cold and the marbles fats cool too much becoming undesirable (in scotch fillet) . If I wrap it in foil and a cloth it seems to loose the nice crisp surface.

SO what is the best way to rest it?

Comment: thankyou TFD that post didn't come up when I seached :-)

Comment: just curious, what did you search for? It is never obvious, and I sometimes think we need a set of search tags different for category tags?

Answer (score 1):

Place the steaks on a wire cooling rack over a half sheet pan and cover with foil.

Additionally heat your plates in either a low oven or your dish washer on the plate warming setting which will help keep the steaks as warm as possible once plated.