# What are the effects of salting a thin steak that's grilled on a pan?

Tags: salt, steak

What are the effects of salting a thin (1/4" to 1/2") beef steak right before being seared on a pan, compared to not salting at all?

(there are no other spices used, salt or nothing).

Does the exact method of preparation matter to the differences (e.g. searing almost-frozen steak vs. thawed out)?

Obviously, I'm interested in effects other than imparting salty flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Related [answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/12571/23376) to the question [Is it okay to salt beef before or while cooking it?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12567/is-it-okay-to-salt-beef-before-or-while-cooking-it)

TL;DR: Salting the steak right before searing does not noticeable affect the tenderness.

Concerning the (semi-) frozen or thawed steak: [Is it bad to cook frozen meat without waiting it to be unfrozen?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18191/is-it-bad-to-cook-frozen-meat-without-waiting-it-to-be-unfrozen)

Since your mentioned steak is quite thin I don't think the semi-frozen steak goes "bad".